# How do I assign an URL for a local server in Linux

Tags: linux

I have a machine I am using as my server, ie, 192.168.1.255. When I want to access that machine from another machine on the Intranet, instead of typing http://192.168.1.255/my_page i would like to use http://mysite/my_page

I don't want to change localhost to another name. On my main machine I don't care how i call it. This for other machines in the network. How can I do this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to assign any url to any IP address in Linux.

Open file /etc/hosts
Add ip address and url, for eg. `192.1.1.255    mysite`

and that's it. So for your machine when you put in `mysite` in the address bar of a browser, the machine will take you the assigned ip address

Comment: Note that has to be done on ***all*** machines on the network in order to make it possible that they can call the URL. That is quite some work and one of the reasons why people came up with a shiny new technology. I think they called it DNS.